# Latitude Longitude format

Tags: gps, format, coordinates

I have a database of gps coordinates in the format below.

```
177508867:34660765
177508977:34660701
177508895:34660777
```

These are displayed in the OEM software as below

```
S 32 13.9235, E 115 50.8867
S 32 13.9299, E 115 50.8977
S 32 13.9223, E 115 50.8895
```

Does anyone recognise the format and know the formula for converting them to get the shown result.
A couple years ago I posted the example above in a forum(I can't remember where) and someone recognised it immediately and posted the formula.
Since then I had a catastrophic hard drive failure and lost my project and the explanatory notes.

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: Di you understand what the OEM software coordinate format is: S 32 13.9235, E 115 50.8867 ? What is 32, what is 115? Which country?

Comment: 32 degrees and 115 degrees

Comment: Australia is the country

Comment: OK, undertsnd the OEM output now, it is in format degress and decimal minutes, also called DM. And you cannot rememeber nothing of the input format.

Comment: Subtracting two constants from the two figures and dividing by two constants converted them.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was provided to me from another forum a couple of days ago.

Split the numbers at the colon.
First number is the Easting or Longitude, second is the Northing or Latitude.

Subtract the Northing number by 54,000,000 and divide by 600,000.
Subtract the Easting number by 108,000,000 and divide by 600,000.

Multiply the decimal by 60 to get the decimal minutes.

Thanks to Andre.